# Simple pipeline script for jenkins and docker

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a simple pipeline script for jenkins that would build the application docker container and run a simple test in it.

```
node('swarm') {
     // My project sources include both build.xml and a Dockerfile to run it in.
     git credentialsId: 'jenkins-private-key', url: 'git@github.com:myrepo/myapp.git'


     try {

        stage 'Build Docker'

            def myEnv = docker.build 'repo_folder/myapp:latest'


        stage 'Test'

            myEnv.withRun {
               sh 'gulp test'
             }

        stage 'Deploy'

            echo 'Push to Repo'

        stage 'Cleanup'

            echo 'prune and cleanup'
            sh 'npm prune'
            sh 'rm node_modules -rf'

        }


        catch (err) {

            currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"

            throw err
        }

    }
```

The build crashes in *Test* and I get an error

> Gulp not found

Comment: `npm not found`.... I need to check if these containers are being built correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have gulp installed inside that container?

Ideally you should install it globally by adding `RUN npm install -g gulp` by the end of your Dockerfile.

If you want a quickfix you could try installing gulp right before running by adding:

```
sh 'npm install gulp'
```

**UPDATE**

So it seems that your container does not have node installed after all, you could use [official images](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) as a starting point in your Dockerfile for example:

```
FROM node:6.3.0
```

Or you could install it yourself, here's a usefull snippet from node official Dockerfile for you to add it:

```
ENV NODE_VERSION 6.3.0
# gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node
RUN set -ex \
  && for key in \
    9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B \
    94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
    0034A06D9D9B0064CE8ADF6BF1747F4AD2306D93 \
    FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
    71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
    DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
    B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
    C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
  ; do \
  gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key"; \
  done

RUN curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" \
  && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
  && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
  && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
  && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
  && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt \
  && npm install -g npm
```

Comment: npm not found.... I need to check if these containers are being built correctly. Thanks

Comment: @Marrento consider accepting my answer if it helped you. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work